# Find number of consecutively increasing/decreasing values in a pandas column (and fill another col with it) in an optimized way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column for a dataframe. The column I use for it is a price column. Basically what I am trying to achieve is getting the number of times that the price has increased/decreased consecutively. I need this to be rather quick because the dataframes can be quite big.

For example the result should look like :

```
input = [1,2,3,2,1]

increase = [0,1,2,0,0]
decrease = [0,0,0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compute the `diff` and apply a `cumsum` on the positive/negative values:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,2,1]})
s = df['col'].diff()
df['increase'] = s.gt(0).cumsum().where(s.gt(0), 0)
df['decrease'] = s.lt(0).cumsum().where(s.lt(0), 0)
```

Output:

```
   col  increase  decrease
0    1         0         0
1    2         1         0
2    3         2         0
3    2         0         1
4    1         0         2
```

##### resetting the count

As I realize your example is ambiguous, here is an additional method in case your want to reset the counts for each increasing/decreasing group, using `groupby`.

The resetting counts are labeled `inc2`/`dec2`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,2,1,2,3,1]})

s = df['col'].diff()
s1 = s.gt(0)
s2 = s.lt(0)

df['inc'] = s1.cumsum().where(s1, 0)
df['dec'] = s2.cumsum().where(s2, 0)

si = df['inc'].eq(0)
sd = df['dec'].eq(0)

df['inc2'] = si.groupby(si.cumsum()).cumcount()
df['dec2'] = sd.groupby(sd.cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Output:

```
   col  inc  dec  inc2  dec2
0    1    0    0     0     0
1    2    1    0     1     0
2    3    2    0     2     0
3    2    0    1     0     1
4    1    0    2     0     2
5    2    3    0     1     0
6    3    4    0     2     0
7    1    0    3     0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {
    'input': [1,2,3,2,1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
diffs = df['input'].diff()
df['a'] = (df['input'] > df['input'].shift(periods=1, axis=0)).cumsum()-(df['input'] > df['input'].shift(periods=1, axis=0)).astype(int).cumsum() \
    .where(~(df['input'] > df['input'].shift(periods=1, axis=0))) \
    .ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
df['b'] = (df['input'] < df['input'].shift(periods=1, axis=0)).cumsum()-(df['input'] < df['input'].shift(periods=1, axis=0)).astype(int).cumsum() \
    .where(~(df['input'] < df['input'].shift(periods=1, axis=0))) \
    .ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

output

```
   input  a  b
0      1  0  0
1      2  1  0
2      3  2  0
3      2  0  1
4      1  0  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Coding this manually using numpy might look like this

```
import numpy as np

input = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1])

increase = np.zeros(len(input))
decrease = np.zeros(len(input))

for i in range(1, len(input)):
    if input[i] > input[i-1]:
        increase[i] = increase[i-1] + 1
        decrease[i] = 0
    elif input[i] < input[i-1]:
        increase[i] = 0
        decrease[i] = decrease[i-1] + 1
    else:
        increase[i] = 0
        decrease[i] = 0

increase  # array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
decrease  # array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```